# Export data in csv using bat file

Tags: sql-server, csv, sqlcmd

I'm trying to export my data to a `csv` file using the command below. I am using `-s`, for comma delimited.
It's working fine but I face one problem when my customer name has comma(,) inside. In this case it's cutting the customer name in two different column.
How do I resolve this issue?

```
sqlcmd -S . -d MYDB -E -Q "set nocount on; select 'customer_id','customer_name','salesrep_id'; select customer_id,customer_name,salesrep_id from customer where customer_id=106866" -b -o C:\customer.csv -h-1 -s, -w 700
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be nice to know your datatypes.  But generally put varchar in double quotes.  Here's the very basic idea:

```
select customer_id, '"' + customer_name + '"', salesrep_id from customer where customer_id=106866
```

I generally like to explicitly create the csv line myself, so my selects usually look more like this:

```
select '"' + customer_id + '","' + customer_name + '"," + salesrep_id + '"' from customer where customer_id=106866
```

If there are columns that are numbers, then I convert the column to varchar and don't put double quotes around it.

Based on your comments:

Here is a .cmd file that I use in production to create a .csv file:

```
set proc=NoBillsReport
sqlcmd -E -S win11.net.davisbrownlaw.com -d ProLaw -Q "exec %proc%" -h -1 -W > "c:\2019\no-bills.csv"
```

It uses a stored procedure and redirects the output instead of trying to have SQL do the output.
Here is a simplified version of my stored procedure:

```
--Header row
select '"Matter ID","Client Sort","Matter Description","Billing Initials","Area of Law","Fees No-Billed","Costs No-Billed"'

-- Costs that were no-billed in previous month
select '"' + matterid + '","' + clientsort + '","' + shortdesc + '","'
   + initials + '","' + areaoflaw + '",' + convert(varchar(50),nobilled_fees)
   + ',' + convert(varchar(50),nobilled_costs)
from Matters
```

And its output:

```
"Matter ID","Client Sort","Matter Description","Billing Initials","Area of Law","Fees No-Billed","Costs No-Billed"
"70441233","ACME","Closing Wheel, Whenever","LA","IP",0.00,7.98
```

which works great as the contents of a .csv file.

The stored procedure is nice because it doesn't all have to fit on 1 long command line.  But, for your use, I think this has a shot at working:

```
sqlcmd -S . -d MYDB -E -Q "set nocount on; select '""customer_id"",""customer_name"",""salesrep_id""'; select convert(varchar(50),customer_id) + ',""' + customer_name + '"",""' + salesrep_id + '""' from customer where customer_id=106866;           " -h -1 -W > C:\customer.csv
```

Note that this is called from a .cmd file.  The double double quotes might be different if called directly from the command line.  Also, *on my system*, the 11 spaces after the `;` at the end of the sql line **is necessary** due to how the double double quotes are consolidated.  And yes, there are single quotes and double double quotes all over the place.
Based on further comments, here is how I script a .cmd file to pull year, month, day:

```
:: Get current year/month/day
for /f "skip=1 tokens=2-4 delims=(-)" %%a in ('"echo.|date"') do (
    for /f "tokens=1-3 delims=/.- " %%A in ("%Date:* =%") do (
        set %%a=%%A&set %%b=%%B&set %%c=%%C)
    )
)
set /a "yy=10000%yy% %% 10000 %% 2000 + 2000,mm=100%mm% %% 100,dd=100%dd% %% 100"
:: Pad with leading zeros if needed
set mm=0%mm%
set mm=%mm:~-2%
set dd=0%dd%
set dd=%dd:~-2%
```

Then your filename would be `"customer%yy%%mm%%dd%.csv"`

Comment: I have tried below but didn't work. It didn't create CSV file.
I also want to include header but my some of customer name include (,) inside when CSV create i want to see full customer name in only customer_name column which was cutting in my previous command 
customer_id = decimal(0) datatype
customer_name = char datatype
salesrep_id = char datatype

sqlcmd -S . -d MYDB -E -Q "set nocount on;select customer_id, '"' + customer_name + '"', salesrep_id from customer where customer_id=106866" -b -o C:\customer.csv -h-1 -s, -w 700

Comment: @RaviPatel I added to my answer.

Comment: Thank you so much.
it worked like charm.
thanks a lot

Comment: Sorry one more question.
can I append some number to file name? For example customer20191010.csv
so If i can have two different files in same exported folder.

Comment: Certainly, at least manually.  To automate it, you can pull the year month day from the command line into variables.  I'll update my answer with code . . .